# number of solution of inequality $b^2 < (a-1)(c-1)$

Tags: inequality

I want to find the number of unique triplets that satisfies the inequality
$b^2 < (a-1) (c-1)$ for some $A,B,C$ where $1<=a\leq A$,  $1<=b\leq B$,  $1<=c\leq C$.

The method which I am trying is to simplify the equation to $b*$b < $(a-1)(c-1)$ and then solve  $b <(a-1)$ and $b < (c-1)$ but this approach is not giving me any general solution.

Comment: See my answer: Is the restriction that $a>1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand the RHS to

$$b^2 < ac-a-c+1 \implies b^2<c(a-1)-a+1\implies c > \frac{a+b^2-1}{a-1}$$

As $a>1$ and $(a+b^2-1) > 0$, the third inequality shows that $c$ is greater than a finite positive number. There are infinitely many values of $a,b,c$ which satisfy this inequality as we are free to choose $c$ larger than the RHS of the third inequality.

Answer (score 0):

NO, this is not how to solve an inequalty.

$$3^2 \le (11-1)(3-1)$$

but this does not implies that $3 \le (11-1)$ and $3 \le (3-1)$

However, let put $b=0$ than there are infinitly many solution of that inequality i.e. there is not a finished number of triplets that satisfy that inequality.

Comment: well what if all three are greater than 1 and are less then some finite n. Is it possible to solve it?

Comment: If you buond with some constants A,B,C and you are searching for integers solutions then yes, there are finitely many. If you search also for real solutions then the answer is no.